# SSIS Package how to successfully do a foreach or for loop to auto increment a value for field insert?

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, foreach, ssis

First of all I have never attempted something like this in SSIS and I am very new to SSIS package development.

I need to build a component in my package that will run through a table of data (say 80 rows) and set a field titled DisplayOrder to the auto incremented number. The catch is that one of the records HAS to be set to 0 and then the rest of he records set to the auto incremented number.

In regards to code, I am not even sure what code to attach to this question or even what screenshots.

Comment: How do you determine which record gets set to 0?

Comment: @JohnS I would have to select the record by name which is unique.

Comment: @JohnS ... Actually the record that would be changed to 0 on the display order would have to be manually added. Should make this process much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out and there is no need for a loop.

1. Create a SQL Task to clear the linked Table.

**Script Used**

```
DELETE FROM [Currency].[ExchangeRates]
```

2. Create a SQL Task to clear the main table.

**Script Used**

```
DELETE FROM [Currency].[CurrencyList]
```

3. Load the values into the main table.

**Actions Used**

- Load values from XML Source
- Dump values to [ExchangeRates] Table

  4. Create a SQL Task to load the Values from the main table to the linked table.

**Script Used**

```
INSERT INTO [Currency].[CurrencyList] (CurrencyCode, CurrencyName, ExchangeRateID, DisplayOrder) SELECT [er].[TargetCurrency] AS [CurrencyCode], [er].[TargetName] AS [CurrencyName], [er].[ID] AS [ExchangeRateID], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ER].[TargetName]) AS [DisplayOrder] FROM [Currency].[ExchangeRates] AS [er] ORDER BY [CurrencyName]
```

5. Create a SQL Task to load a new record to the main table for use as DisplayOrder 0.

**Script Used**

```
INSERT INTO [Currency].[ExchangeRates] ([Title], [Link], [Description], [PubDate], [BaseCurrency], [TargetCurrency], [TargetName], [ExchangeRate]) VALUES ('1 USD = 1 USD','http://www.floatrates.com/usd/usd/','1 U.S. Dollar = 1 U.S. Dollar',(SELECT TOP 1 [PubDate] FROM [Currency].[ExchangeRates]),'USD','USD','United States Dollar','1')
```

6. Create a SQL Task to reference the newly created record from the main table.

**Script Used**

```
INSERT INTO [Currency].[CurrencyList] (CurrencyCode, CurrencyName, ExchangeRateID, DisplayOrder) SELECT [er].[TargetCurrency] AS [CurrencyCode], [er].[TargetName] AS [CurrencyName], [er].[ID] AS [ExchangeRateID], 0 AS [DisplayOrder] FROM [Currency].[ExchangeRates] AS [er] WHERE [er].[TargetCurrency] = 'USD'
```